# "Heavy Metal" comic back-issue with a story about a woman restrained on a table and tortured, who ended up defeating her captor

Tags: comics, episode-identification

I know this is a long shot, but I’m wondering if anyone can help me track down a back issue of *Heavy Metal*. I had it in my late teens, so I’m assuming it was an early 2000’s issue, but it may have been a bit later.

All I can mainly recall is that there was one story with a woman restrained on a table and being tortured by having her arms broken. She ended up defeating her captor by biting his crotch, and in the last frame, both of them collapsed on the table. Pretty sure the story was in black and white.

I do also vaguely recall that the first story in the issue was in colour with very realistic artwork, and I seem to remember a muscular bearded man.

Sorry, I know this isn’t much to go on, but I’ve been searching the internet to no avail and thought I’d post here on the off-chance that the right person sees it, haha. Annoyingly, I can’t remember the cover, but I am 90% sure it was a *Heavy Metal* issue, maybe even a special issue like a Summer special or something, but don’t quote me on that.

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your question if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)